# remove the system dependencies of ROS package?

Tags: ros, rosdep, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After installing a ros package, when I did rosdep check <package_name> , it has displayed some missing system dependencies that were not taken care of, during apt-get install . So, I installed them using rosdep install. However when I want to remove the ros package ,

*sudo apt-get purge ros-**

*sudo apt-get purge python-ros**

*sudo apt-get autoremove*

running the above three commands seem to be removing only the ros dependencies and not the system dependencies. How do I remove the system dependencies as well in this case? Thank you.

PS: I am trying to install only a single ros package on Ubuntu 16.04 ARM.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255210/remove-the-system-dependencies-of-ros-package?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since you used rosdep to install them they are selected to be installed in the dpkg database. If you ask rosdep to simulate the install and to reinstall you can get a list of all the system dependencies you may want to remove. Though be careful removing them as they may be shared dependencies with other things that you want.

Use
`rosdep install --simulate --reinstall ...`

where `...` is the same arguments you used to install and uninstall the packages you don't want anymore.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0